# Where can I find the parameters to find an agent user id needed to access Google's Test Suite for Smart Home?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I am well accustomed to the Byzantine depths of Google's documentation but this has me baffled. On this page: https://smarthome-test-suite.appspot.com/ I have the Service Account Key but not the Agent User ID.

https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/tools/smart-home-test-suite tells me that to I need to:

Open the OAuth Playground tool.
Click on the gear icon in the upper right corner to open the OAuth 2.0 configuration dialog.
In the OAuth endpoints field, select Custom.
Specify the following account linking parameters, using the values you set in the Actions console when you created the smart home project. Click Close to save your changes.
Authorization endpoint: Set this parameter to the Authorization URL in the console.
Token endpoint: Set this parameter to the Token URL in the console.
OAuth client ID: Set this parameter to the same value as in the console.
OAuth client secret: Set this parameter to the same value as in the console.

How am I expected to remember parameters I set when I created the Home project? I don't see any place where the parameters are recorded for me to retrieve. Google has all this stuff. Why isn't there an idiot proof step to retrieve it?

Can anyone help me retrieve the agent user ID?

Answer (score 1):

The auth and token endpoint URLs as well as the client ID and secret used to retrive your `AgentUserId` should match the information that [you entered in the Actions console](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/implement-oauth#configure_account_linking_in_the_console).

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the Account Linking page tells me what is needed but not where to find it. I've given up on this project...